# VBA Match value from listbox object to range

Tags: vba, excel, listbox

I am trying to check items in a listbox according to a range of cells (that matches)

This is what I've done so far.

```
Dim j As Integer
Dim lItem As Long
Dim rowx as Long

rowx = 12

j = 0
For lItem = 0 To Worksheets("Bordereau Prep").ListBoxPlot.ListCount

    If Worksheets("Bordereau Prep").ListBoxPlot.List(lItem) = Worksheets("Liste").Cells(rowx, 40 + j) Then
        Worksheets("Bordereau Prep").ListBoxPlot.Selected(lItem) = True
        j = j + 1
    End If

Next lItem
```

This does what I want, checking the items in the list that are in `range_pr_el` but it throws an error at :

```
If Worksheets("Bordereau Prep").ListBoxPlot.List(lItem) = Worksheets("Liste").Cells(rowx, 40 + j) Then
```

Telling me "Error 381 : Impossible to read List property. Index of the property table not valid". And I don't understand why, because it does enter the loop, and it does do what it's supposed to. What is missing to correct the error?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
For lItem = 0 To Worksheets("Bordereau Prep").ListBoxPlot.ListCount - 1
```

When going through the for loop the last iteration will have lItem equal the number of list items. However, the list index starts at 0 so there should be a difference of 1.

For example if you had 1 list item the .ListCount method would give you 1 so the for loop will try to access list item with index 0 and list item with index 1. This would give you an error because the list box doesn't have 2 items.

`